# How to exclude some fields of a Simple POJO from getting logged in the logfiles/console

Tags: spring, log4j

Hi I am trying to think to restrict the password to not get logged in the logging console as I feel insecure exposing password such a way. How do I exclude the particular variable from logging on the console/file? We can consider all the scenarios here, Application server logs, logstash logs, GCloud logging. Just want to exclude it be shown there. Below is the simple request.
I know Transient do not work here but just added it for restriction on files.
Below is the the request from the UI with the input payLoad passed to the Login API

```
{
    name:"testLog";
    password:"Password@1243124242o955";
    text:"eerere";
    address:"hrerhjelr";

}
```

My Login API accepts the request into a request body

```
 public ResponseEntity<User> login(@RequestBody User userRequestPayLoad) 
 {
   LOGGER.info("User details {}",userReqPayload); //Payload
   --login validation
   --blah---
   --blah---  
  }
```

Below is the mapped User POJO

```
 class User implements Serializable{
String name;
@Transient
String password;
String text;
String address;

}
```

Comment: You have a method toString already implemented. Just remove the password part there.

Comment: Ok I will remove it , but what if it comes from a UI source and I accept it in my LoginAPI under a userRequestPayload?

Comment: Please share the code you are talking about. And an example of current log.

Comment: Edited the code for clarity

Answer (score 0):

Depending on `toString()` or `@Transient` is not reliable. One of logging appenders can use reflection and thus read every single property.

More reliable approach would be following. Create a copy of the object, remove any sensitive attributes like password and use this sanitized copy for logging. Then you don't need to care how the logging is done, because you just don't pass any sensitive data to the logger.

Comment: I think this seems to be a vague approach. Would like to know something straightforward. One of the indirect examples is there anything like this https://docs.payara.fish/community/docs/documentation/payara-server/logging/exclude-fields.html

Comment: @Learner: No. I explained why it is bad. There can be *multiple* appenders. One is writing to console. Another is writing to files. Another one is sending log events to Elastic Search or to Splunk. Ans so on. You cannot enforce all of them to ignore some fields. You cannot force them to create JSON string from Java object that you send them. Basically, you send password to multiple parties (appenders) hoping that none of them will use it...

Comment: ... You **can** do it, but it will be **error prone**. For instance, if some new developr comes to your team and adds an appender that is convenient for some specific case, e.g. decides to send logging events additionally to a database to simplify analysis. Or send to Kafka. Thus all data including passwords will be sent to other services.

Comment: ... But if you make sure that your data do not contain anything sensitive, then it does not matter what appenders are used, password will not be sent to them.

Comment: Agree, but I think there should be some utility either from spring or java to exclude these. Aren't there any such that are straightforward? If in case we want to send to external systems or Kafka we can send with @JsonExclude always.

Comment: Replying to your first comment, --- it will be a bad design if sensitive information is free flowing in the system or other systems IMHO. I think there should be some flexibility. the thing is I was asked this scenario in an interview and he said about using some framework PCI or something. The question looked good to me. Really sensitive info like password, token should not be displayed in the consoles which I feel uncomfortable with. Do you agree?

Comment: *"it will be a bad design if sensitive information is free flowing in the system or other systems"* - Exactly. But this is what you propose. You suggest to delegate to loggers/appenders what will be written to the log. Until then such sensitive information will be flowing in the system. That's why better is to clear it as soon as possible, i.e. *before* sending any data to the logger. Some logging libraries like LogBook provide filtering out of the box. But LogBoot applies such filters to the content received (like XML, JSON). t is not used, if you log Java Objects.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/253085/discussion-between-mentallurg-and-learner).